# Call PHP function variable from separate file

Tags: php, html, json

I have a class function that calls JSON from a URL. That function then sets a list of variables from the results of the JSON.

What I am attempting to do is call back one of those strings from inside of another file (index.html). I do not receive any errors back, however the results are blank.

I'm sure it's not due to the json command because it works properly when not placed inside of a class/function. To be sure I attempted to add `$somestring4 = 'this is string 4'` into the ClassFile.php and call it - it was also blank.

Here is my code...

ClassFile.php

```
<?php
class newClass { 

Function newFunction(){
$jsonFetched = file_get_contents('http://url.com/file.json'); //<== MISSING SINGLE QUOTES ADDED FOR CODE-READABILITY...
$jsonQuery = json_decode($jsonFetched);

$someString1 = $jsonQuery->level1->level2->string1 ;
$someString2 = $jsonQuery->level1->level2->string2 ;
$someString3 = $jsonQuery->level1->level2->string3 ;
    }
}       

$foo = new newClass; 
?>
```

Call from Index.html

```
<?php  
include($sitePath . '/classes/ClassFile.php') ;
$refClass = new newClass();
$someString3 = $refClass->newFunction();
echo $someString3;
?>
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: `$someString1 !== $someString3`; nor does your `newFunction()` return anything to be assigned to any variable; not to mention the missing quote in the first line of `newFunction()`

Comment: new newClass(); instead of new newClass);

Comment: its just syntax, that's why i added a comment but not an answer

Comment: A blank page when output is expected in PHP usually means a fatal error (several syntax/parse errors as pointed out already). Always when developing and testing code, enable PHP's error display, at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` -- you will see PHP complaining about a few things, like the missing quote on the `file_get_contents()` call.

Comment: Sorry, those were typos on my part when rewriting my code for the post.

Comment: I have error reporting turned on and I receive no errors.

Comment: @DataBox Why not copy and paste?

Comment: Can you clarify the output you hope to get? Your `newFunction()` does not `return` any value. So, `$someString3` will never have a value when you call that function and assign its result.

Comment: @cybermonkey - I not trying to get put on blast my by ugly code. I know little about php and could probably assign the json tokens a lot easier than line by line.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - The answer from Khaled explains what I am attempting to do better than I can explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
class newClass { 
  public $jsonFetched = '';
  public $jsonQuery = '';
  public $someString1 = '';
  public $someString2 = '';
  public $someString3 = '';


function newFunction(){
    $jsonFetched = file_get_contents('http://url.com/file.json');
       $jsonQuery = json_decode($jsonFetched);

       $this->someString1 = $jsonQuery->level1->level2->string1 ;
       $this->someString2 = $jsonQuery->level1->level2->string2 ;
       $this->someString3 = $jsonQuery->level1->level2->string3 ;
    }
}       


?>

<?php  
include($sitePath . '/classes/ClassFile.php') ;
$refClass = new newClass();
$refClass->newFunction();
echo $refClass->someString3;
?>
```

Comment: This is PHP.  `$this->` not `$this.`

Comment: you're missing a `$` at `public someString3='';`

Comment: This seems to put me in the right direction! However, I get **Notice: Undefined variable: jsonFetched in /ClassFile.php** referring to `$this->jsonFetched = file_get_contents('http://url.com/file.json');`

When defining a variable by `$this->someString4 = 'this is string 4';` it works perfectly.

Comment: Removing `this->` from jsonFetched and jsonQuery fixed the error. Thank you for the help! @Khaled